# Unconventional behavior with json array and an upppercase pipe filter for a number

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

***Updated question*:
An uppercase pipe filter for a number would not make any sense, but that itself has bought this question to live, so posting**

If I have an array of JSON objects as below

```
export class ProductListComponent {
    show: Boolean = true;
    public products: any[] = [
        {
            "name":"Person1",
            "age":30,
            "salary"": "100"
        },
        {
            "name":"Person2",
            "age":32,
            "salary"": "100"
        },
        {
            "name":"Person3",
            "age":34,
            "salary"": "100"
        }
    ]
}
```

And in my template i have the parsing as

```
<div *ngFor = "let product of products">   
   Name : {{product.name| uppercase }} <br />
   Age :  {{product.age | uppercase }} <br />
   Salary: {{product.salary }}
</div>

<button (click) = 'show =!show'>Click to see unconventional behavior </button>
<div *ngIf='show'> Someother div to show or hide based on show value,
  but not way related to products json arry </div>
```

Now when the page is loaded first time output is

```
Name: Person1 
Salary: 100
```

But when i click on the button, I get the page with the details of Person 2 as well.
i.e.

```
Name: Person1
Salary: 100
Name:  Person2 
Salary: 100
```

and when i once again click on the button, I get the page with the details of Person 3 as well.
i.e.

```
Name: Person1 
Salary: 100
Name: Person2
Salary: 100
Name: Person3 
Salary: 100
```

Should not the button click be no way related to the JSON Object rendering?

Comment: How does `show` relate to the `products` array??

Comment: it wont, actually show is used to show or hide, someother div below , which i have omitted to make the code simpler, But when i click that button, the above div is rendering the next item of the json array list. that seems little unconventional

Comment: When you ask a question you need to create an [mcve]. The behavior above cannot be reproduced. https://plnkr.co/edit/zBD4iplOQ5JzMNPZDSEj?p=preview

Comment: Also correct syntax in the posted code helps so others do not have to fix it while trying to reproduce the "issue"

Comment: lgor, you are missing the pipe upper case to the product.age. when i edited your plnkr, the beheviour is seen which i meniton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic problem (not syntax). You can't apply an [uppercase](https://angular.io/api/common/UpperCasePipe) pipe to a number (`age`). This will cause an exception in your template. Any behavior/execution that does occur after an unhandled exception is unpredictable. Remove the pipe from `age` and everything works as it should.

[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/zBD4iplOQ5JzMNPZDSEj?p=preview)

Next time I recommend you open your browsers console (debugging tools) where you can see if there are any errors being emitted. In this case you would have seen:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '32' for pipe 'UpperCasePipe'

Comment: i accepted it as an answer but still i would like to put forward my point, i agree that age is a number and an uppercase pipe on it is not a valid (which i knew before posting the question), but my whole point is still why such unconventional behavior if done that way. Anyways if we conclude that any unhand-led exception would later trigger an unpredictable result, then there wont be any further point to discuss.